# Entity framework - Model from database, change in database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I generated model from existing database in c# via entity framework, but when i change database (for example add column to table) application stop work, because in model miss the new column, but i don´t need the new column. Is there any solution to generate model from database, but do not be independent to change in db?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding a column to your table shouldn't stop your application from working. You can add a column to your table without mapping it to your `Model`.

Comment: Please provide the error you get in your application after adding the column.

Comment: Removing or renaming column is the problem, but not adding